# jquery to read div field dynamically and update

Tags: jquery, html

If I have 2 field inputs and the #pricein field input is populated with a number dynamically from another script.

```
<form>
    How much do you want to spend 
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="pricein"/>
    <br /> 
    This is how much you will spend
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="priceout"/> 
</form>
```

how can I get jquery to read that number as it changes and display it in the #priceout field? An onclick or a keypress that triggers it wont work because it changes without an action. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programmatically changed values, you can't detect it with an event.  Instead, integrate with the other script's code.  If it is not under your direct control, run your code whenever the other script should run. For example, on click of some element. If that is not possible, and the other script is truly unpredictable, as a last resort, you could use a timer.

```
(function (){
    var lastValue = $("#pricein").val();
    setInterval(function() {
        if ($("#pricein").val() != lastValue)
            lastValue = $("#pricein").val();
            valueChanged();
        }
    }, 500);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery's change()?
http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
    $(function(){
       $("#pricein").change(function() {
          $("#priceout").val($(this).val());
       })
    })
```

Comment: live is deprecated. We try to keep people up to date, so we use .on() now in 1.7.

Comment: no, that didnt work. any other ideas to make it recalculate dynamically?

Comment: That won't work.  The `onchange` event is not fired when a value is changed programmatically: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/qm8v5/

Answer (score 1):

As your `#pricein` is dynamically created so you need [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on) for delegate event binding like following:

```
 $("form").on("keyup", "#pricein", function() {
    $("#priceout").val( this.value ); // OR $(this).val()
 });
```

Syntax of `.on()` for live event delegation is:

```
$(StaticParent).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction )
```

Where, `StaticParent` is any selector which is not dynamic and parent of `target` element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the initial script? If so, can you trigger the keyup action like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WRMyX/1/
(thanks, gilly3)